# Android SQLite is empty after inserting ContentValues with first loading using onCreate() method

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, insert

**I am new in android development so the code is not completed yet....**

When I created my DB and insert some items inside with using `contentValues` in the `onCreate()` method but after the app is running, I tried to read my DB but it was empty. 
That is the first time to launch my app so it will use the `onCreate()` method but unfortunately not inserting.

That is my code here...

```
package com.example.axel.spotopia;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    import java.security.PublicKey;



    public class SpotopiaDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String DB_NAME = "spotopia";
        private static final int DB_VESION = 1;

        public SpotopiaDBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VESION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            updateMyDB(db, 0, DB_VESION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            updateMyDB(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }

        private void insertSpot(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String address, String note, String rank) {
            ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
            content.put("NAME", name);
            content.put("ADDRESS", address);
            content.put("NOTE", note);
            content.put("RANK", rank);
            db.insert(DB_NAME, null, content);
        }

        private void updateMyDB(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            if (oldVersion < 1) {
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE SPOT  ("
                        + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                        + "NAME TEXT, "
                        + "ADDRESS TEXT, "
                        + "NOTE TEXT, "
                        + "RANK REAL);");
                insertSpot(db, "jaz", null, null, "8");
                insertSpot(db, "jaz1", null, null, "9");
                insertSpot(db, "jaz2", null, null, "10");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
db.insert(DB_NAME, null, content);
```

First parameter should be Table name... and not, Database name. So, could you please test with code below?

```
private void insertSpot(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String address, String note, String rank) {
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put("NAME", name);
    content.put("ADDRESS", address);
    content.put("NOTE", note);
    content.put("RANK", rank);
    db.insert("SPOT", null, content);
}
```